# Continuous function vanishing on dense open subset

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I am trying to understand a line in a proof given in Perrin's Algebraic Geometry book. The proof is that a morphism of affine varieties $\varphi:V\rightarrow W$ is dominant (that is, the image is dense in the codomain) if and only if the induced map on coordinate rings $\varphi^*:\Gamma(W)\rightarrow\Gamma(V)$, sending $f$ to $f\circ\varphi$, is injective.

Supposing $\varphi$ is dominant and $f\in\operatorname{Ker}\varphi^*$, we have $f$ vanishes on $\varphi(V)$. The next line says, "since $f$ is continuous, $f$ vanishes everywhere".

Why is this quoted last line true? I am not sure if this is a general topology fact or something to do in particular with the Zariski topology.

Comment: What do you mean by "vanishes" for a general space $Y$?

Comment: @Mark Yeah I guess that isn't clear. The example I had in mind was the Zariski topology on affine algebraic sets.

Comment: Hint: show if $f:X\to Y$ is continuous, $U\subset X$ is dense, $C\subset Y$ is closed, and $f(U)\subset C$, then $f(X)\subset C$. This is purely topological.

To apply it to your problem, you'll need to select the correct things to play the part of $f,X,Y,U,C$.

Answer (score 0):

No in general: if $X$ is the cofinite topology on an infinite set, and $Y$ is indiscrete you can find many counterexamples. Trivially yes if  $Y$ is Hausdorff.